# Django ModelForm add data to context

Tags: django

On a ModelForm I have some fields that depend on the other. For example,

```
class FactorForm(ModelForm):
    //field definitions

    class Meta:
        model=Factor
        fields=['name', 'type', 'sets']
```

`sets` is a select that depend on the `type` which is also a select. When `type` is changed, I should update the options of the `sets`. Therefore, I would like to put a list of fields to the template (i.e., refresh=['type']), so a JavaScript function can replace the form when a field given is changed.

So, how can I put random data in the forms context?

I can do that by overriding `get_context_data` with generic CBV's. But the ModelForm has no such method.

Preferably, I would like to put the common logic in a ModelFormParent function, and list my refreshing fields under Meta:

```
class FactorForm(ModelFormParent):
    //field definitions

    class Meta:
        model=Factor
        fields=['name', 'type', 'sets']
        refresh=['type']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override init:

```
class FactorForm(ModelForm):
    //field definitions

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.refresh = ['type']
```

And then in your template:

```
// something like:
{{ form.refresh }}
```